# ¿Cómo lleno un select con otro select a otro select?

Tags: php, javascript, select

Tengo un formulario de 3 select y solo he podido rellenar los 2 primeros.

Mi idea es rellenar el primero y me de las opciones según la selección  (esto ya lo tengo) y en base a la segunda selección muestre las opciones del tercero.

He intentado replicarlo haciendo lo mismo con el "onchange" y llamar a otra función para que realice lo mismo que las 2 opciones primeras, pero no logro que funcione o si podría modificar mi código para adecuarlo y  funcione para las 3.

Les dejo mi código:

```
    <form name="depa1">
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Departamento</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <div class='input-group'>
                                <select class="form-control" name="departamento_ticket1" onchange="cambia_opcion1()">
                                  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">SELECIONA OPCION</option>
                                  <option value="1">ENPUNTO TRANSPORTE</option>
                                  <option value="2">TYCINPYME.  NEGOCIOS</option>
                                  <option value="3">TYCINHOME. RESIDENCIAL</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
                              </div> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Asunto</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                              <div class='input-group'>
                                <select class="form-control" name="asunto_ticket1">
                                  <option value="-">- </option>
                                </select> 
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></span>
                              </div> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Problema de su producto</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="mensaje_ticket">
                                  <option value="-">- </option>
                                </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

el script es el siguiente:

```
<script>
 var opcions_1=new Array("-","OBSTRUCCION DE CAMARAS","CORTES EN LA GRABACION","VIDEO LOSS","IRIS CAMARA DAÑADO","FALSO EN LAS CAMARAS","CAMARA(S) MOVIDA(S)","...");
  var opcions_2=new Array("-","CCTV","VIDEOPORTERO","ALARMA","CERCA","La Pampa","...");
  var opcions_3=new Array("-","PENDIENTE 1","PENDIENTE 2","PENDIENTE 3","PENDIENTE 4","...");

  var todasopcions = [
    [],
    opcions_1,
    opcions_2,
    opcions_3,

  ];

  function cambia_opcion1(){ 
    //tomo el valor del select del departamento_ticket elegido 
    var departamento_ticket1 
    departamento_ticket1 = document.depa1.departamento_ticket1[document.depa1.departamento_ticket1.selectedIndex].value 
    //miro a ver si el departamento_ticket está definido 
    if (departamento_ticket1 != 0) { 
        //si estaba definido, entonces coloco las opcions de la opcion correspondiente. 
        //selecciono el array de opcion adecuado 
        mis_opcions=todasopcions[departamento_ticket1]
        //calculo el numero de opcions 
        num_opcions = mis_opcions.length 
        //marco el número de opcions en el select 
        document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.length = num_opcions 
        //para cada opcion del array, la introduzco en el select 
        for(i=0;i<num_opcions;i++){ 
          document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.options[i].value=mis_opcions[i] 
          document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.options[i].text=mis_opcions[i] 
        } 
    }else{ 
        //si no había opcion seleccionada, elimino las opcions del select 
        document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.length = 1 
        //coloco un guión en la única opción que he dejado 
        document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.options[0].value = "-" 
        document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.options[0].text = "-" 
    } 
    //marco como seleccionada la opción primera de opcion 
    document.depa1.asunto_ticket1.options[0].selected = true 
}

  </script>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Tu código no está completo. ¿Dónde están las funciones `onchange` de cada uno de los `select`? Solamente veo una.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya intenté declarando otro "onchange"  en el segundo select para que lo tome como en el primer select y agregando otro script igual cambiando los nombres y no me lo reconoce.